# How I remove \ in R

Tags: r

How I remove `"\"` in text, I tried `gsub('\', '',y,fixed=TRUE)`, it gave me the error, I tried `str_replace()`, it didn't work either

```
"c(\"OTHER\",\"WHITE\")"    "c(\"HISPANIC OR LATINO\")"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the escape for the double quote

```
gsub('"', "'", y)
#[1] "c('OTHER','WHITE')'    'c('HISPANIC OR LATINO')"
```

#### data

```
y <- 'c(\"OTHER\",\"WHITE\")"    "c(\"HISPANIC OR LATINO\")'
```